# asp.net vb CheckBoxList Selected from CSV

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I am learning asp.net and needed to have a CheckBoxList which items will be initially selected if the are in a CSV string from a database.

I have got it working although I just wondered if I have gone about it the best way as it seemed a little long winded?

Thanks for any help provided.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="rh_type" runat="server" CssClass="chkbox" 
RepeatLayout="Flow" CausesValidation="True">
<asp:ListItem>House</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Flat/Apartment</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Bungalow</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Any</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

**CODE**

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str_rh_type As String = "House,Bungalow"
    Dim split As String() = str_rh_type.Split(","c)

    For Each s As String In split
        'Response.Write(s & "<br />")

        For i = 0 To rh_type.Items.Count - 1
            If rh_type.Items(i).Text = s Then

                rh_type.Items(i).Selected = True

            End If
        Next

    Next s

End Sub
```

Thanks again
J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is functional but maybe some tweaking for maintainability would help.  Also not sure you necessarily need nested loops to load your drop down items.

This should be just a reference point to make your own decisions on coding practices.  Certainly what works for some doesn't work for others.

Here's how I'd code this...

ASP.NET Control:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListHomeType" runat="server" 
    CssClass="chkbox" RepeatLayout="Flow" CausesValidation="True" />
...
```

- ID of `CheckBoxListHomeType` is easy to remember and intellisense will get me the rest of the way. (or another common approach would be `cblHomeType` as the ID).  Getting intellisense to help on a name like `rh_type` may be just as easy but IDs that resemble what kind of control it is can really help when maintaining code

VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        LoadHomeTypes()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub LoadHomeTypes()
    Dim houseTypes = "House,Bungalow,Flat/Apartment,Any"
    For Each houseType As String In houseTypes.Split(",")
        CheckBoxListHomeType.Items.Add(New ListItem(houseType))
    Next
End Sub
```

- Keeping the logic in a separate `LoadHomeTypes` function can make the code more readable.
- Creating a new `ListItem` while iterating the list of `homeTypes` should remove the need to iterate over the CheckBoxList items, (if you need to clear out the existing ones you can add `CheckBoxListHomeType.Items.Clear()` to the top of the function)
- the `Not Page.IsPostBack` check prevents the need for loading the drop down values every postback, unless you have need for them to change.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, there are a few things that won't work due to what i'm trying to do but a few helpful pointers there....thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the good answers , try this

```
Dim ds As DataSet
    ds = Insertstu.searchrec(txtsearch.Text)
    txtnm.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("stuname").ToString()
    txtadd.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("stuaddress").ToString()
    txtph.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("stuph").ToString()
    rdobtnsex.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("sex").ToString()
    Dim arr As String()
    Dim quali As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("qualified").ToString()
    arr = quali.Split(",")
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each itm As String In arr
        For i = 0 To chkqualify.Items.Count - 1
            If chkqualify.Items(i).Text = itm Then
                chkqualify.Items(i).Selected = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

''chkqualify is checkboxlist id